# How to deserialise child classes?

Tags: yamldotnet

I have a list which holds items of the same base class but of different child classes. How can I deserialize this?

For example

```
class Base {
}

class Child: Base {
   int Property { get; set; }
}

class Ser {
   public List<Base> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer has no way to infer automatically which child type you are expecting. Therefore you need to tell it the type of the child using a tag. E.g:

## YAML

```
- !!child
  Property: 1

- !!child
  Property: 2
```

## C#

```
var deserializer = new Deserializer();
deserializer.RegisterTagMapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:child", typeof(Child));

var items = deserializer.Deserialize<Ser>(...);
```

[I have put together a working fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GZtqvL)